# OPEN-CV error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I am trying to get the images from a streaming video, and I get it for a few minutes, but then I get the following error: cv2.error: OpenCV (4.1.1) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp: 3720: error: (-215: Assertion failed)! ssize.empty () in function 'cv :: resize'
My code:

```
while True:

ret, frame = video_capture.read()


small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)


rgb_small_frame = small_frame[:, :, ::-1]

#
if process_this_frame:

    face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_small_frame, number_of_times_to_upsample=2)
    face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_small_frame, face_locations)

    face_names = []
    for face_encoding in face_encodings:

        matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
        name = "None"

        # #
        # if True in matches:
        #     first_match_index = matches.index(True)
        #     name = known_face_names[first_match_index]

        face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
        best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)
        if matches[best_match_index]:
            name = known_face_names[best_match_index]

        face_names.append(name)
        if matches[best_match_index]:
            adicionar_json()

process_this_frame = not process_this_frame

font = cv2.FONT_ITALIC





for (top, right, bottom, left), name in zip(face_locations, face_names):

    top *= 4
    right *= 4
    bottom *= 4
    left *= 4
```

I am trying to get video streaming from an rtsp camera

Answer (score 0):

It's an unsuccessful frame-read. When you do a frame read, it returns the frame and a Boolean indicating whether the read was successful - to test/prevent the kind of issue you're facing.

Try this:

```
ret, frame = video_capture.read()

if ret:
    [frame processing code]
```

Comment: I did this however the error persists, it spends more time streaming but still get the same error. Debuging the code I get the message: cv2.error: OpenCV (4.1.1) C: \ projects \ opencv-python \ opencv \ modules \ highgui \ src \ window.cpp: 352: error: (-215: Assertion failed) size .width> 0 && size.height> 0 in function 'cv :: imshow'

Comment: This only happens when I use the RTSP camera, when I use the webcam I get no error.

Comment: There is no `imshow` in the code you pasted, so I can't say. But you can test it by putting (another) `imshow` right below the frame read. If the error does not occur at that new imshow -  then the image read is not the problem